# My load() function in jQuery Is Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load an external HTML file into a div.
I tried using `load()` function in jQuery but it's not working.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#content').load("1.html");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is "1.html":

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <p>This is demo text.<p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: by the way, it is a local file and both of these files have saved in one folder

Comment: *"it's not working!!!"* means what? error in console? nothing happens?

Comment: If these are local files, CORS settings will most likely stop it from working as there is no origin in at all this case. Try using some simple development server. Or, if you want to stick to local files, take a look here: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/

Comment: Could be that the url for the resource you are requesting for is wrong, or CORS issues. Some logs from the server or the browser console will be helpful

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code just make sure that you have correct path to the file i.e `1.html` codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-liskov-88s7y

Comment: Side note that you are trying to load a complete document into another document.  That is going to create invalid markup.  You should be loading page fragments instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't load local files with JavaScript like that because of security concerns. As @ZorgoZ said, you should use a local web server, like [Apache httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/) or [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) for Node.js.

If you really need to load the file inside the webpage, why not use an `<iframe>`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="content" src="1.html"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

You can't access the DOM inside `<iframe>`s, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: No idea , i even took out the time to create a sandbox , to show that the code works and i still get a downvote